# power bi how to count Safe / On Risk value for multi columns

Tags: powerbi

how to count Safe / On Risk value for multi columns and make Pie chart for all columns

the target is to calculate how many (Safe) and how many (On Risk) in all columns

example

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Power Query Editor**, create a new table using this below code-

**Please** replace **your_table_name** in this below code with your original **Table name**.

```
let
    Source = your_table_name,
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Helmet", "Goggels", "Shoes", "Gloves"}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Value"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**Keeping Location in the result set"-

```
let Source = your_table_name,
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Location", "Helmet", "Goggels", "Shoes", "Gloves"}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {"Location"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Location", "Value"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**Output** will be as below-

[image]

**Output with location**-

[image]

**Now** you can create your **Pie Chart** using this new table and the final output will be as below-

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply , but there is error coming

Comment: @AhmedKamel You are doing this under "Data" window which is not going to work. You need to go "Transform Data" and then add new tables in the "Power Query Editor" window.

Comment: thanks now it is coming but if i want to make slicer and select location i want this value to change with the selected location

Comment: means that i have 2 table now so how i can make relation between them

Comment: i try to add location but it is now working , please still need your support

Comment: @AhmedKamel, I also added code for Location. Hope rest you can configure :)

Comment: Thanks a lot now it is working file , appreciate you kind support

Comment: @AhmedKamel, nice to hear that it working. You can also give and up vote to the answer :)